# Expecting ')' kotlin Unresolved reference: tag

Tags: kotlin

первый день обучения kotlin следую по гайду и тут возникла ошибка перепроверил 100 раз

```
package com.example.kiddinchat

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import com.example.kiddinchat.databinding.ActivitySignInBinding
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.IdToken
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class SignInAct : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var launcher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var binding: ActivitySignInBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        auth = Firebase.auth
        launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(it.data)
            try {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                if(account != null ){
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
                }

            } catch (e: ApiException){
                Log.d(tag: "MyLog", msg : "Api excpetion")
            }


        }
        binding.bSignin.setOnClickListener {

        }

    }
    private fun getClient(): GoogleSignInClient{
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    }
    private fun signInWithGoogle(){
        val signInClient = getClient()
        launcher.launch(signInClient.signInIntent)
    }
    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String){
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(IdToken,null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener{
            if(it.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(tag: "MyLog", msg: "Google signIn done")
            } else {
                Log.d(tag:"MyLog", msg: "Google signIn error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

вы не можете использовать именованные параметры в данном случае.

`Log.d(tag:"MyLog", msg: "Google signIn error")`

просто уберите "tag:" и "msg:"

`Log.d("MyLog", "Google signIn error")`

Comment: даже если бы и можно было (именованные параметры только для kotlin классов), то они всё равно через `=` пишутся, а не через `:`

Answer (score 0):

убрал tag:  и msg: и все заработала. Спасибо !!!